# How to add commas in thousands and to show decimal upto 2 places on X/Y axis in Angular chat JS?

Tags: angularjs, django, chart.js

How to add commas in thousands ( ex 1000 will be 1,000) and to show decimal upto 2 places  (3.55555 will be 3.55) on X/Y 
   axis in Angular chat JS ?

```
  <div
  class="col-md-6"
  ng-if="$ctrl.projection_data.chart_type == 'bar'">
  <canvas
    id="bar" class="chart chart-bar"
    style="height: 400px"
    chart-series="$ctrl.projection_data.series"
    chart-data="$ctrl.projection_data.data"
    chart-labels="$ctrl.projection_data.labels">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey shashank, Can you be a little more specific. Think of how this question looks to others, given your information.

Comment: @MichaelBruce i added an example. Take a look

Answer (score 0):

I found the following link may be useful
[Angular JS: API: number](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)

they provide the following code snippet, which may prove usefull

```
    <script>
  angular.module('numberFilterExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.val = 1234.56789;
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Enter number: <input ng-model='val'></label><br>
  Default formatting: <span id='number-default'>{{val | number}}</span><br>
  No fractions: <span>{{val | number:0}}</span><br>
  Negative number: <span>{{-val | number:4}}</span>
</div>
```